# Cant see SQL Server Agent in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, sql-server-agent

I have SSMS 2012 installed on my laptop, and SQL Server 2012 on my hosting, but when i try to schedule a sql job i didn't find "SQL Server Agent" in the left side list!!?

Comment: You need to identify: (a) whether your local SQL Server instance is Express or not; (b) whether the hosted SQL Server instance is Express or not; (c) whether your copy of Management Studio is the Express edition. For (a) and (b) you can check using `SELECT @@VERSION;` in a query window against each instance, and for (c) you can check `Help | About` in the application.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this question is not a duplicate, as it refers to SSMS, the link specifically refers to SSMS express. In SSMS it could for instance also be that the person does not have sufficient rights to view SQL server agent.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Management Studio Express installed (any version prior to SQL Server 2012 SP1), it simply doesn't contain any facility for SQL Server Agent (no matter which edition you're trying to manage). You can fix this by getting the very latest version from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

You want the file `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` (or the one with `x86` in the name if you have a really old 32-bit machine). This is the first version of Management Studio that has been offered fully functional and license-free.

Once you install this version of Management Studio, you will have access to SQL Server Agent when managing any instances of the SQL Server engine that support SQL Server Agent. Of course that won't help you create jobs on instances of SQL Server Express, since it doesn't have Agent at all.

Comment: You can check which version is currently installed by going to about and checking the product version against [this listing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Express doesn't have the SQL agent (the service gets installed but you can't enable it) so you won't see any of this section in SSMS.

If you want to schedule tasks you will have to use SQLCMD and the windows task scheduler.  This article explains how to schedule backups in this way, but the same principle can be used to run any SQL script:

[How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698)

Comment: so how can i schedule SQL server job!!?

Comment: I've added some extra info to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

As steoleary said, SQL Server 2012 Express doesn't support SQL Server Agents

Only the following SQL Server 2012 editions support SQL Server Agents: Enterprise, Business Intelligence, Standard and Web

See all the features by edition on MSDN: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Mgmt_tools)